# Add custom tool (inherited class from tool) to the Microsoft Visual Studio toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Basically, I have these checkboxes which could be checked for 1 or more reasons, so I'd like for those checkboxes to store a List of Reasons as to why it is checked. If the list size is greater than 0, the checkbox would be checked. So if the check box had 3 reasons why it was checked, and one reason was removed, the checkbox should remain checked.

Of course I could just make it a separate list, but I think it'd be cooler to just have an inherited class with the list. (The user wouldn't have direct access to the checkbox, but could see whether or not it is checked.)

PS. I'm still a beginner at coding and c#. My programs are usually silly little things.

I'm thinking my code would look something like this:

```
class myCheckBox : CheckBox
{
  List<Reason> Reasons = new List<Reason>();
}
```

From there, I would hope to right click somewhere in the toolbox, find my custom class, and add it to the list. But, I don't see any options like that. I can "Choose Items", but I don't see my custom class anywhere in that list.

I've read a few posts about DLLs, but I feel like that solution might be way over my head.

Comment: Have you "Rebuild"?

Comment: @SemiOptimum, based on my test, I could see the custom class in my toolbox. As others said, could you make sure that you rebuild the project after you created the custom class? As usual, it often lies in the top of toolbox. If you did not see the custom control in toolbox, have you tried to create the control by using the code?

Comment: @JackJJun The categories listed in my toolbox are: All Windows Forms, Common Controls, Containers, Menus & Toolbars, Data, Components, Printing, Dialogs, WPF Interoperability, Custom Tools, and General. Under Custom Tools (and General), it just says, "There are no usable controls in this group. Drag an item onto this text to add it to the toolbox."

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be using a read-only property, not a field. Fields, if required, should always be private and data exposed publicly via properties. In the case of a collection, the property should be read-only so that you can get the existing collection in order to add or remove items but you cannot replace the existing collection with a completely new one.

Secondly, you need to use a collection type that raises an event when it changes, so that you are notified if the state of the check box needs to change. The `List<T>` doesn't provide that but the `ObservableCollection<T>` does.

```cs
public class ConditionalCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public ObservableCollection<Reason> Reasons { get; }

    public ConditionalCheckBox()
    {
        Reasons = new ObservableCollection<Reason>();
        Reasons.CollectionChanged += Reasons_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Reasons_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Checked = Reasons.Any();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        Reasons.CollectionChanged -= Reasons_CollectionChanged;
    }
}
```

That creates the collection and adds an event handler for when the collection changes in the class constructor, then checks the control if and only if the collection contains at least one item when that event is raised.

Note also that a more appropriate name has been used for the class. Always begin a type name with an upper-case character and don't use `my` for anything other than in quick tests or demos.

By the way, that code requires the following namespace imports, although VS should have been able to add them for you:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```